# Bangla text gets broken on tkinter GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, bangla-font

I am trying to create a GUI Application in Tkinter. I want to show Bangle ('বাংলা') text on a text label.

This is what the text looks like in a file.
[image: Here]

But this is what it looks like on the GUI
[image: Here]

As you can see the words gets broken.
The text is in Unicode format, which is first read from a file. I am using ubuntu 20.04 and the input method is "m17n". I use m17n for typing Bangla in Unicode, which doesn't create such a problem.

Also, I have tried many Bangla fonts like 'Kalpurush', 'Lohit Bengali' etc (native Bangladeshi viewers will understand) but none of them worked.
Any solution?

Comment: maybe it is a font problem, try changing that with `font` attribute

Comment: @Matiiss tried that. No luck.